# cassandra read performance for blobs

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I started using cassandra (2.0.9) and encountered a performance problem when selecting many rows that contains a blob.

I created this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, data blob)
```

Used this insert query to insert 10000 rows:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, data) VALUES (?,?)
```

for each row data contained a random 10KB byte array.

Performing this query:

```
SELECT id, data FROM my_table LIMIT 1000
```

took about 7 seconds.

Is this the peformance I should expect or am I missing something?
Any tips for getting better performance in such a case?

I have only one cassandra node. And the queries are done using the c# driver.

Comment: According to my knowledge you will not get better performance compare to what you are getting now..

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Maybe I can get better performance in a similar use case, say if I have the ids I want in advance and query for them. Currently I see similar numbers when I try it.

Comment: Are you using the default configuration, or have you tuned it? What's the underlying machine and O/S?

Comment: Default configuration. The server runs on a powerful windows machine and the client on a standard windows machine. Any pointers for configuration tuning?

Comment: On my windows machine, the query runs in 175 milliseconds. The load takes 4.67 seconds. That's with the default config.

Comment: Google for tuning docs. Also, provide more info on the language you're using, or better yet, a full code example.

Comment: I can't provide a full code example at the moment, but I'm using datastax c# driver 2.0.3 with .net 4. I now notice that when I run the query in cqlsh with trace on I also get about 170 ms as the trace output. So the actual query isn't the problem. I'm guessing it's the communication between the processes that's taking long, even on the same machine.

Comment: The language I'm using is Java, with the DataStax driver. That could be the difference.

Comment: This is a strange query to run on Cassandra in an application. I presume this is some sort of playing around / connectivity test?  Also deploying on a single machine is a big no-no.

Comment: For that matter, deploying Cassandra on Windows is not meant for production either.